# how to read line by line in a text file and populate a pointer to object array

Tags: c++

Using the solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c/51572325) thread, I have a general idea on how to read line-by-line in a text file. My issue arises on how to populate that data into my phonebook, a pointer to an array of objects.

This is what my text file outputs.

```
Albert, Fred
4541231234
8888 Avenue Drive

Doe, John
6191231234
1234 State Street

Smith, Mike
8791231234
0987 Drive Avenue
```

What I want to do, is to parse through each line and use whatever information it takes to populate my Phone Book, which is defined as.

```
class AddressBook
{
private:
    Contact* phoneBook[maxSize]; //array of contact pointers
    ...etc
}

class Contact
{
public:
    Contact();

    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    std::string name; //lName + fName
    std::string phoneNumber;
    std::string address;
};
```

I can get it to read line by line, at least I think, but I don't know where to start on how I can get it to recognize if it's a first name, last name, phone number, or address since they're all strings.

```
void AddressBook::writeToFile(Contact * phoneBook[])
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream myFile("fileName.txt");
    if (myFile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myFile, line))
        {
            //do something
        }
        myFile.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the contents of the file in groups of four lines.

```
std::string line1; // Expected to be empty
std::string line2; // Expected to contain the name
std::string line3; // Expected to contain the phone number
std::string line4; // Expected to contain the address.
```

And, instead of the `while(getline(...))` statement, use:

```
while (true)
{
   if ( !getline(myFile, line1) )
   {
      break;
   }

   if ( !getline(myFile, line2) )
   {
      break;
   }

   if ( !getline(myFile, line3) )
   {
      break;
   }

   if ( !getline(myFile, line4) )
   {
      break;
   }

   // Now process the contents of lines
}
```

You can simplify that a little bit by using an array for the groups of lines

```
std::string lines[4];
while ( true )
{
   // Read the group of lines
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
   {
      if ( !getline(myFile, lines[i]) )
      {
         break;
      }
   }

   // Process the lines
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu where is the `true` coming from?

Comment: @TylerLe. Loop until one of the `getline` calls does not succeed. At that time, you break out of the loop.

Comment: @R Sahu Another thing that I forgot to mention, with the name, I need to also separate them into last and first name. As you can see in the text file, it goes `lastName, firstName`, So I need to store Albert as a last name variable and Fred as a first name variable. How can I separate the two and not include the commas? Other than that issue, I got it to work thanks to your contribution!